# How do I use redux-form/immutable with plain immutable library?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, immutable.js

I'm a ReactJS beginner. This how my store is created as of now

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reducer as usersDataReducer } from 'data/reducer'
import { reducer as authReducer } from 'scenes/Main/scenes/Auth/reducer'
import { reducer as sessionReducer } from 'services/reducer'

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  data: usersDataReducer,
  scenes: authReducer,
  session: sessionReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
  form: formReducer,
})

export default createStore(appReducer, compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
))
```

I successfully integrated `redux-form` in my app. However, all reducers in my app are using plain `immutable` library so I'd like to use `redux-form`'s immutable version for consistency. I have no idea because in `redux-form`'s documentation, the [example](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/immutable/) requires using `redux-immutablejs` library. It adds complexity to the already complicated `redux-form`. I'd like to use plain `immutable` library and if it's not encouraged, I'd need help to integrate `redux-form/immutable` + `redux-immutablejs` in my current setup. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I learned that you just need to use `redux-form/immutable` instead of just `redux-form` anywhere in your code.